# Weka does not discretize last column

Tags: weka, data-mining

I am using Weka to discretize data, but the problem is that it does not discretize last column. Also supervised.Discretize is inactive. Is it a problem with dataset?

The dataset:

```
@relation R_data_frame

@attribute V44 numeric
@attribute V178 numeric
@attribute V280 numeric

@data
0,3.7,8
0,17.6,6
0,14.2,10
...some more data
```

Complete data set:
https://pastebin.com/raw/RmQ2pD3W

Comment: I am tried using weka 3.8.3 and 3.9.3 versions. Same result. openjdk version "1.8.0_171"

Answer (score 2):

Supervised attribute discretization requires that the class variable is categorical. Yours is numeric, so it is not an option.  However you *can* get this to work with supervised discretization. First select

```
filters -> unsupervised -> attribute -> Discretize
```

[image: Weka Window 1]

Next click on the text box that says Discretize (next to the button that says Choose) to set the options for discretization. One of the options is `Ignore Class`. By default, that is False. Change it to be True.

[image: Changing options for Discretize]

Now run the filter by clicking `Apply` and it will discretize all three variables.